# Canceling a daily notification one day, but still show the notifications the rest of the days

Tags: ios, swift

I have this app with a daily notification at 12pm. If the user does something, I want to cancel the notification that day.

Is there a way to cancel the notification that day, but the rest of the days keep working the same?

```
    private func setUpNotification() {

        // Ask Permission
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        }

        // Create content for notification
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "I'm a notification!"
        content.body = "Don't forget to track your cigarretes!"

        // Configure the recurring date.
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

        dateComponents.hour = 12    
        dateComponents.minute = 00

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

        // Create the request
        let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        //Register the request
        center.add(request) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                // Handle any errors.
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```